# How to calculate the mean and SD of a new parameter using two groups mean and SD

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation

Hello I have a problem to calculate the mean and SD of a new parameter using two groups mean and SD.

I have the means X1 and X2 and the SD as S1 and S2
I want to create new parameter Y = X1/X2
What is the is the SD of the parameters Y?

For example someone works 50+-4 hours and a week and sells products with the values of 5653$+-87 a week.
What is the SD of the sells per hours of this worker?

I have read about [error estimation](http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys261/F06/ErrorPropagation.pdf) on this kind of things but I could not find for SD.